# lllegal character in path resolved by Maven

Tags: maven

I tried to download 
`compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69-el6.x86_64.rpm` from Artifactory, but I get the below error:

> Illegal character in path at index 89: `http://artifactory-apj-itc.ca.com:8081/artifactory/apm-releases/com/ca/apm/binaries/rpms/>compat/libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69/>compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69-el6.x86_64.rpm`

I think the problem is with + sign. Is that supported by Maven?

Comment: Since it has nothing to do with Artifactory, I removed it from title and tags.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. According to the exact path you pasted, the problem is the `>` character, which is illegal in all Windows and Linux file and directory names, not only with regard to Artifactory.